# Defining partial view's parent through controller action mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

A controller action returns a partial view. The parent element and ajax definition for this partial view is generally defined in ajax javascript.

However, is it possible to define the parent element for the partial view in the controller action itself and eliminate the need for Javascript code?

Comment: you could tell the element name or id via controller but you have to set the element content via javascript

Comment: Ya I can pass a JSON indicating the parent's name but I think it would be great if I can call an action method from javascript and the action method will automatically render the partial in the parent element.

Comment: The thing is that the controller's role is not to arrange elements in a page, there you are only able to work with the data passed to your view. I do not think the action method could automatically render the result in some element decided when the action is done. You either make some javascript logic in the partial view to render itself in some element based on some value sent via ViewBag(i can give you an javascript example for this if you like) or you decide when you make the javascript call for that action that returns the partial view what the parent should be(but this you already knew).

Comment: In a dynamic application it becomes very complex to handle all the code javascript,C# so I thought it would be great to eliminate some of Javascript  and let the controller action handle it. But you are right it's not the controller's role... there wouldn't be a V in the MVC then.